# accessing a WCF Service in a browser

Tags: asp.net, xml, wcf, iis, xpo

I'm trying to access to a WCF webservice from my browser but when i click on the WCFfile from VS10 and "*View in browser*" it shows me:

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 3 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name
>
> Below is a
> rendering of the page up to the first error.

I'm using XPO as ORM and VS10, IIS8, SQL SERVER 2012 Express edition. I've been browsing forums but found no solution.

Comment: Wow. _That's_ how you troubleshoot? Browse the Internet? What's at line 3, column 2?

Comment: Well.. i'm executing a .svc file which is supossed to show on browser an xml file containing data in the .xpo model!

Comment: What **binding** is your service using? Seeing you have an `.svc` file, it's most likely using a SOAP binding (like `basicHttpBinding`) and in this case, you **cannot** test the service just with a browser - you need a real **SOAP client** like the WCF Test Client or [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org)

Comment: i'm  using DevExperience's XPO !

Comment: i fixed this problem by installing IIS Express integrated with VS2012. now i'm using it.. and it works fine.